# How to add and delete textfields on a view when click on add and delete buttons in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to add a textfield on button click but i am unable to delete the textfields that i have added, i am only able to delete the recent textfield that i have added but unable to delete the other previous textfields, how can I delete/remove those textfields in Swift.

I have successfully added the buttons but i am unable to delete those textfields.

I have tried to get those tag values for each textfield but here I am missing some logic please help in this regard. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Below is the image for reference when i click on delete(-) button then with respect to that textfield must be removed not all the subviews.

// for add method

```
@IBAction func btnAddOptionAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    txtOption = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(52, yFrame+17, 195, 30))
    txtOption.borderStyle = .None
    txtOption.tag = index
    let modifiedURLString = NSString(format:"Option %d", index) as String
    //textField.text = modifiedURLString
    txtOption.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:modifiedURLString,
        attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])
    txtOption.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir Medium", size: 16)
    txtOption.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.scrOptions.addSubview(txtOption)


    btnDeleteOption.frame = CGRectMake(259, txtOption.frame.origin.y + 8, 25, 25)
    btnAddOption.frame = CGRectMake(259, txtOption.frame.origin.y + txtOption.frame.size.height + 10, 25, 25)

    btnDeleteOption.hidden = false

    print("Add index", index)

    index++
    yFrame = yFrame + 40

    scrOptions.contentSize = CGSizeMake(0, btnAddOption.frame.origin.y + btnAddOption.frame.size.height + 20)

}
```

//For delete method

```
@IBAction func btnDeleteOptionAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    yFrame = yFrame - 40
    index--
    sender.tag = index

    txtOption.removeFromSuperview()

    imgoption.removeFromSuperview()

    imgUnderLine.removeFromSuperview()

    btnDeleteOption.frame = CGRectMake(259, yFrame - 15, 25, 25)
    btnAddOption.frame = CGRectMake(259,  yFrame + 32 - 15, 25, 25)

    if index <= 1
    {
        btnDeleteOption.frame = CGRectMake(259, 25, 25, 25)
        btnAddOption.frame = CGRectMake(259,  25, 25, 25)

        btnDeleteOption.hidden = false

    }

    print("y-axis ",btnDeleteOption.frame.origin.y)




}
```

Comment: Are you using removeFromSuperview? Can post your code so that we can help

Comment: in your viewDidLoad, include the delegates for the text fields. and later in btnDeleteOptionAction, try self.textFields.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: i have already given delegates to my textfield, you clearly observe i am using only one textfield and every time i am adding a new textfield with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var myTag = 0

if let myView = UIView() {
    view.addSubview(myView)
    myView.tag = myTag++
}

if let viewWithTag = self.view.viewWithTag(myTag) {
    viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

It must remove the last element

Comment: for your solution i can not delete only the previous textfield, for that method you provided, i will delete all the subviews it contains.

Comment: Whenever i am providing "self.view.subviews.last" then i am getting this error - Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'Generator'

Comment: For the above code optional binding cannot be done on UIView.

Comment: Yes it is removing the last one but what about the above one, it also be deleted.

Comment: just calculate necessary tag and delete this one via provided code ;)

Comment: No @Orkhan Alizade its not working once i am removing that "viewWithTag.removeFromSuperview()" from next time onwards i am getting nil value.

Comment: do you change your `myTag` variable before the second removing?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all subviews.
After removing all subviews add required textfield in the view.
Hope it helps.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var updateIdView: UIView!


let  textField: UITextField = updateIdView.viewWithTag(textFieldTag) as! UITextField
     textField.removeFromSuperview()
```